# I need to unwrap/parse snmp results

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

Let me preface this with I know next to nothing about SNMP but I am learning.  I am trying to get the device name from a printer.
I get the '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0' OID.  But it has a lot of additional information in it and I think it's some type of wrapper, but I don't know how to unwrap it.

Here are the results of my get

```
varBinds=[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(ObjectName('1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')), DisplayString(b'OFHP1', subtypeSpec=ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 65535)), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255)), ValueSizeConstraint(0, 255))))]
```

the printer name is OFHP1.  That's all I need.  Is there a command to unwrap this, or do I need to just parse it by brute force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to SNMP, you typically deal with so called variable-binding or OID-value pairs. That is conceptually similar to key-value pairs that you may encounter in other applications.

So your `varBinds` is a list of objects, each object represent a ket-value pair. To get the value you need to traverse that down to the component you need:

```
varBind = varBinds[0]  # first var-bind
oid, value = varBind   # unpack var-bind into OID and value
```

Now, values in SNMP are typed and constrained (they are actually ASN.1 types). That is why they are not just base Python types, but specialized objects. But you can strip extra information they carry and get a pure Python string (or int) from any SNMP scalar:

```
py_value = str(value)           # turn SNMP value object into Python str
py_value = value.prettyPrint()  # turn SNMP value object into a MIB-guided, human friendly representation
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed.